# Beginner: How to fix 'ReferenceError myFunc is not defined' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm new to JavaScript and trying create a very simple image slider. I also trying to understand `onclick=""` event with the error return.

I've learnt how to write a function and assign it into the event for `<button>`.

HTML Setup:

```
<div id="custom-slider">
  <button onclick="sliderPrev()">Prev</button>
  <img id="slider" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" />
  <button onclick="sliderNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

myJavaScript in external file: (before the closing `</body>`)

```
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

myJavaScript Setup:

```
var images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/400/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/400/200"
];

var num = 0;

function sliderPrev() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = images.length - 1;
  }
  slider.src = images.length;
}

function sliderNext() {...}
```

I've created my JS in external file and `sliderPrev()` for the `Prev` button. However everytime I try to click the button and it keep return `ReferenceError: sliderPrev is not defined`.

I have no idea what's going wrong in my code. I also try simple testing but still not working at the end.

Simple Testing:

```
function sliderPrev() {
    alert("Testing");
}
```

In my research, I found someone is saying using `onclick=""` event is consider a very bad practicing We should use `addEventListener`: (is that true?)

```
var button = document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("click", sliderPrev);
```

See my code [at here](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3rljkzoqm)!

Comment: Are you sure your external JS is running? Try `console.log`ging at the very top of the script. `We should use addEventListener` Definitely, avoid inline handlers!

Comment: You need to use ready handler.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar That won't affect his current onclick attribute not working (in fact, may break things if the `sliderPrev` etc is not defined on the top level)

Comment: ah, you're right.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added ```console.log``` and found 2 HTMLButtonElement. I'm sure that the external JS is running well?

Comment: OMG! It work for now! I have added ```.addEventListener``` as event handlers instead of using ```inline handlers```!

Comment: Sounds like your functions weren't defined on the top level, so they weren't assigned to `window` (though from the code posted, they appear on the top level...)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Do you mean try to write ```window.onload = sliderPrev();```?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm trying to understand what do you mean, but I'm so blur with this. Sorry :(.

Comment: If the Javascript is as you've posted, verbatim, then it's on the top level, which means that function declarations will be assigned to `window`. The error you describe would only occur if those functions are somehow *not* assigned to `window`, implying that they're not actually on the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the local variables and functions defined inside `index.js` in other files.

To expose `sliderPrev` to the browser, you should add the `window.sliderPrev = sliderPrev` to your `index.js` module, this way you can use it in the html files.

Comment: No. The issue was that, there was a error in the JS file. He is not using any export/import/module concepts. So the JS file included will be in window scope only by default

Comment: weird, I tried to modify his example as I said and it worked for mehttps://codesandbox.io/s/m348wwy5oy

Comment: @motia It work at both. I don't understand why also. What is this method call(is it under DOM section)? ```window.sliderPrev = sliderPrev```. I think I didn't learn about this.

Comment: @KeerthiKumarP It don't work under [scrimba](https://scrimba.com/c/cDLBRKCd) but it did work if added ```window.sliderPrev = sliderPrev```. I didn't actually added ```import "./styles.css";``` this indo my ```.js```. It set by default.

Comment: `window` is a global variable. In the browser `window.sliderPrev` and `sliderPrev` mean the same thing. ( in the web console check `document === window.document` // true)

The variables you define in `*.js` files are scoped to the file where they are defined. So to access them in the browser you should assign them to the `window` global variable as attributes `window.sliderPrev = sliderPrev`.

Comment: @AndersonKoh Had a look at the scrimba link you provided. The way the JS is included is different from your question :) @motia The scrimba version, when I look in developer tools, includes `index.pack.js` in it's  HTML. If this is the case, module concepts is indeed in play and the only solution is to use `window`. My solution is when the JS is included as is without any bundling/module stuff.

Comment: @AndersonKoh Having said that, using `addEventListener` is a better approach than using `window`. It is considered as best practice

Comment: Thanks @motia for the clarify.

Comment: @KeerthiKumarP I'll take note for ```addEventListener``` thanks! For the scrimba version I not sure but it does return an error same as my question. If I remove the ```window.sliderPrev = sliderPrev```, this error came our ```ReferenceError: sliderPrev is not defined``` . Have you try before?

Comment: @AndersonKoh Yes for the scrimba version you have to use `window.sliderPrev` solution only Or `addEventListener` also will work. The solution of removing the `import` statement will not work. It is because the `index.js` is not included directly.

Answer (score 1):

Looked at your code in the link you have given in the question and i see the following line

`import "./styles.css";`

This is the issue. This has to be removed. This is causing a error and hence further JS code is not run. So the function `sliderPrev` is not at all getting defined.

To import CSS styles you need to use the following in your HTML inside `<head>`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">`

Comment: Thanks! It does work after i remove the ```import "./style.css";```.